# How to extract specific row from dataset and append into another list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I Have a Dataset. of Big mart sales. First I select column (ITEM_TYPE ) and then use a for loop to match the ( Dairy ) from whole column. I'm facing a problem I could not get the whole row. i,m the beginner
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsGHb.png)

```
mainlist
df = pd.read_csv('bm_Train.csv')
dt =df['Item_Type']
list_of_item = dt.to_list()

i=1
for x in list_of_item:
    if x=="Dairy":
        mainlist.append(dt[:i])
i+=i

mainlist
```

Comment: You can get all rows that match "Dairy" in column "Item_Type" by doing the following : `df[df["Item_Type"]=="Dairy]`.  Your code contains plenty of errors though

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the dataset based on `'Item_Type' == 'Dairy'`, you can try with the following code.

```
df_new = df.loc[df['Item_Type'] == 'Dairy'].copy()
```

On the other hand, if you only want the values of the `'Item_Type'`

```
list_of_item = df['Item_Type'].unique().tolist()
```

Otherwise, please let me know what you want.

Comment: I want to make new list or csv file. and append the whole row of dataset which hold Item_Type =='Dairy'

Comment: @Muhammad_ Hamza Could you please tell me why you change the answer to unaccept after writing that it works for you?. Please, let me know, and maybe I can add more information to answer your doubt

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the contents of rows matching the filtering criteria into a list, you can use `.loc` to filter the contents and then use `.values.tolist()` to convert the rows contents into a list, as follows:

```
mainlist = df.loc[df['Item_Type'] == "Dairy"].values.tolist()
```